# How do I set up offline authentication for UWP app?

Tags: c#, xaml, authentication, uwp

I want to make an app that the user logs on to without the need for a server or internet connection, but I don't know how to securely store a password on the user's machine.

Comment: Why would you not use the authentication mechanism that comes built-in to your OS?

Comment: "I don't know how to securely store a password on the user's machine" - Maybe use [PasswordVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.passwordvault?view=winrt-19041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encrypt the password or other information in your app and save it into a local file or a database.

Another choice is that you could use the [Windows Hello authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport).

You could refer to this document about how to protect the data: [Data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/data-protection)

For more information using a MySQL database: [Use a MySQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/mysql-databases).